# angular material - bottom-sheet - extend height

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material, bottom-sheet

How is it possible to control the height of the bottom-sheet?

The [API](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.7/api/service/$mdBottomSheet) doesn't seem to specify this...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the height of md-content as per your convenience.

This is however, a weakness in the framework and something that they'll be fixing soon.

hope this might work